# Structure making array display wrong values

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, structure

Does anyone know why the member `Node_ptr next;` makes the elements of the array `poly[1]` and `poly[2]` display the wrong value? If I remove `Node_ptr next;` from the structure (`struct node`), I'm able to get the correct value for the indexes 1 and 2.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node *Node_ptr;
struct node {
    int coef;
    int exp;
    Node_ptr next;
    };

int main()
{
    struct node p1_terms[] = {10, 1000, 5, 14, 1, 0};
    struct node p2_terms[] = {3, 1990, 2, 1492, 11, 5};

    struct node poly[20];
    poly[0] = p1_terms[0];

    poly[1] = p1_terms[1];

    poly[2] = p1_terms[2];

    printf("Your polynomials are: \n%dx^%d+%dx^%d+%dx^%d", poly[0].coef, poly[0].exp, poly[1].coef, poly[1].exp, poly[2].coef, poly[2].exp);

    int siz = sizeof(poly);
    printf("\n\nSize of the array: %d bytes \n",siz);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `{10, 1000, 5, 14, 1, 0};` wrong initializer list. --> `{{10, 1000}, {5, 14}, {1, 0}}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, (*emphasis mine*)

> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. **When no
>   designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according
>   to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure
>   members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union.** [...]

So, basically, in the initialization

```
struct node p1_terms[] = {10, 1000, 5, 14, 1, 0};
```

the array size is 2. It creates two elements of `struct node` thus accessing `p1_terms[2]` is out of bound access which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, the initialization initializes the structure elements in order, that means, for the above case, the member values will be like

```
p1_terms[0].coef = 10;
p1_terms[0].exp= 1000;
p1_terms[0].next= 5;   // see here....
```

and this is certainly **not** what you want. You need to use the initializer list like

```
struct node p1_terms[] = {{10, 1000}, {5, 14}, {1, 0}};
```

to avoid `next` getting initialized.

Related, from the same chapter

> If the aggregate or union contains elements or members that are aggregates or unions,
>   these rules apply recursively to the subaggregates or contained unions. If the initializer of
>   a subaggregate or contained union begins with a left brace, the initializers enclosed by
>   that brace and its matching right brace initialize the elements or members of the
>   subaggregate or the contained union. [...]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Thank you! That helped me understand what was going on and look for a solution.

Comment: This is true since 89 standard

Comment: The initialization is actually a constraint violation because `5` is not a valid initializer for a pointer.  Yet another example of "helpful" compiler extensions confusing the coder.

Answer (score 1):

Your initialization code `struct node p1_terms[] = {10, 1000, 5, 14, 1, 0};` does not take into account the pointer for the next node. Actually it initializes the 1st pointer to 5 and second one to 0 which is definitely not what you want. Then when you reference a 3rd one with the `poly[2] = p1_terms[2];` there is no data left in the initializer so you are pointing to random data beyond the contents of your array. When you take the `Node_ptr next;` out. 2 ints are consumed per node, so it works as intended.